# Pictures not shown on my computer

Tags: graphics

When I compile my main.tex the pictures wont't show. But when my fellow study partners compile on their acount there's no problem. What causes this?

[image]

Comment: [Welcome to TEX.SE!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436/82917) You are probably using an option `draft` or `demo` somewhere in your code. Please provide a full [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/82917) which reproduces the issue, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: or you have a directory with spaces in its name, or you don't have the files locally

Comment: make sure you are using pdflatex (and not latex+dvips), latex+dvips can not include png files.